# Errors aren't handled automatically by the middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am using Sails v0.10.0-rc4.
I tried to invoke to `res.forbidden( [message] )` from policies, however, it only showed "forbidden" on the page instead of showing 403.ejs. 
In addition, I have also tried to access an undefined action, the response page would show only "not found" instead of 404.ejs.

Update:
When I tried to call `res.notFound();` , `[TypeError: Object # has no method 'notFound']` was shown on the page and terminal.

Snippet :

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.authenticated) {
//        return res.send("You don't have permission to view this page",403);
          return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action.'); //(Error)
//        return res.notFound(); (Error)
//        return res.pageNotFound(); (Error)

    }
    return next();
};
```

Comment: Can you post the full code where you're calling `res.notFound()`?  Also, is this a fresh rc4 project, or an upgrade from Sails v0.9.x?  When you lift Sails, can you verify that it says **v0.10.0-rc4** in the console?

Comment: I have posted my code (where I call `res.notFound();`) above as requested. Yes, it prints `info:    v0.10.0-rc4         |\` on my terminal.